# Random index of a non zero value in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, random, indexing

I hope this hasn't been asked before. Not sure how I can reformulate the question. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414908/how-to-randomly-select-some-non-zero-elements-from-a-numpy-ndarray) is quite similar but still not exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a numpy array with a variable length (something between 4-12). The values of the array are either 0 or 1. I'd like to get the index of a random sample from the array, which is not 0.

My idea was to do something like this:

```
def sample(self):
        flag = 0
        while flag == 0:
            sampleValue = randint(0, len(myArray())-1)
            flag = myArray()[sampleValue]
        return sampleValue
```

But that's not really good code and will eventually get trapped in a never ending while loop. Of course I could improve this. Chances are high there's a much more beautiful way of doing this in python :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the indices where an array `a` is nonzero with `numpy.nonzero`

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
>>> idx_nonzero, = np.nonzero(a)
>>> 
>>> idx_nonzero
array([0, 2, 4, 5, 6])
```

and then choose one of these values with `numpy.random.choice`.

```
>>> np.random.choice(idx_nonzero)
5
```

Comment: Wow python is so awesome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can first generate the list of indices that are ones with:

```
my_idcs = np.where(my_array)[0]
```

then you can randomly obtain one of the indices, for example with `random.choice`:

```
from random import choice

my_idx = choice(np.where(my_array)[0])
```

this will thus return a single index where the corresponding value `my_array[my_idx]` is `1`.

Note that if there are no `1`s in `my_array`, then this will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Thank you very much! In terms of efficiency compared to @timgeb 's solution: Is one of those much faster, or will the executed code in the back be almost the same?

Comment: Yep, `np.where` with one argument is equivalent to `np.nonzero`. I never liked that functionality of `np.where`. I'd rather have this removed and `np.where` renamed to `np.ifthenelse`. :)

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon: normally the difference in time will be very small since in essence both are running the same algorithm. I agree with timgeb that the `np.where` was a bit "sloppy" nomenclature, but I did not invent that :).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Sorry that I can't give both of you the credits.